# Change outlook mailitem selection from c# outlook add-in in conversation view

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I need to select a mailitem from my outlook add-in. I'm trying to use

```
Outlook._Explorer explorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();  
explorer.AddToSelection(item);
```

and it's ok, but only if "Show as conversations" flag is not checked. When it's checked, i'm getting an error "The method you are invoking is invalid for a conversation view." How can i select a mailitem, when "Show as conversations" flag is checked?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can use AddToSelection when Conversations are enabled. However there are a number of other conditions outlined in the link below that could prevent it from working. Just make sure to call Explorer.IsItemSelectableInView(Item) before calling AddToSelection.

Explorer.AddToSelection Method (Outlook)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868732(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: No, you cannot, and it's noted in the documentation for Explorer.IsItemSelectableInView method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868297(v=office.15).aspx 

"The IsItemSelectableInView method raises an error if the current view is a conversation view."

AddToSelection method raises the same error under this condition.

Comment: You're right - I should have tried it.  AddToSelection doesn't mention that it can't be used in a Conversations view but it should.